# All directional derivatives vanish does not imply function is constant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Are there functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which every directional derivative in a certain point vanishes but the function is still not constant?

I thought about something like the following: $f(x,y)= \sin x$, if there is a $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$ but $f(x,y)=0$ everywhere else. Does this work?

Comment: How about $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Ok yeah of course....but what about the function I proposed. Is it right that all directional derivatives in (0,0) vanish?

Comment: It works at $(0,0)$, yes. However, note that there is no neighborhood of $(0,0)$ on which your function is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about one point then, no it need not be constant. For example
$$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$$
then 
$$\nabla f|_{(0,0)} = (0,0)^T$$
However if all direction derivatives vanish everywhere (or on some open set), and $f\in C^1$, then yes, $f$ must be constant. See this post [All partial derivatives 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130639/all-partial-derivatives-are-0). Also note $\nabla f|_{(x,y)}\cdot (1,0)^T = 0$ implies $\partial_xf|_{(x,y)} = 0$ and similarily for all other partial derivatives.

Comment: Actually, I think that for any domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, if $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has vanishing partial derivatives (without any other regularity), this implies that $f$ is locally constant along all vertical and horizontal lines, thus is locally constant thus is constant.

Comment: What about $f(x) = x^2y$, and $\Omega = \{(x,y) \ | \ x=0\}$, then $\nabla f|_{\Omega} = (0,0)^T$? There are no "vertical lines" in this domain. But yes you are right, as the post I linked to you just need the partial derivatives to vanish on an open set, and not the more strict requirement that $f\in C^1$.